# how to query the top 10 most occurrence record

Tags: php, mysql

I am troubled on how to query the top 10 most occurrence ascending. I want to display the total rows/count of tour_id.

Example : 
   - - 
   tour_id | total count 
    94         ->          2
    95         ->         1 
    96         ->         3 
    97         ->         1 , etc

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tourism_most_viewedtbl` (
  `tour_most_id` int(12) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `tour_token` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tour_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `ip_address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `tour_date_time` datetime NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`tour_most_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=28 ;


INSERT INTO `tourism_most_viewedtbl` 
(`tour_most_id`, `tour_token`, `tour_id`,`ip_address`, `tour_date_time`) 
VALUES
(12, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 96, '::1', '2014-06-11 06:59:05'),
(13, '9922c520efa6cfb682a18512166132dd', 96, '::1', '2014-06-11 06:59:54'),
(14, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 97, '::1', '2014-06-11 07:07:03'),
(15, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 94, '::1', '2014-06-11 07:30:35'),
(16, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 95, '::1', '2014-06-11 07:51:15'),
(19, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 98, '::1', '2014-06-11 09:07:32'),
(24, '8062ac76d8c9e9917e1ee1c6430e0c07', 99, '::1', '2014-06-11 10:00:34'),
(25, '973cc524bbde8da4d88cd5f7e47fb513', 96, '::1', '2014-06-11 02:31:03'),
(26, '973cc524bbde8da4d88cd5f7e47fb513', 94, '::1', '2014-06-11 02:31:29');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select tour_id, count(*) as total_count
from tourism_most_viewedtbl
group by tour_id
order by total_count desc
limit 10
```

Comment: I think OP wants `ASC` instead

Comment: does mysql let you order by the name of an aggregate?

Comment: @user3678068: I doubt that. **Most** occurences is `desc`

Comment: @JoePhilllips: Yes, it does allow ordering by an alias.

Answer (score 0):

As per your Desired OP, you have to try somthing like this:-

```
SELECT tour_id, COUNT(tour_most_id) AS total_count
FROM tourism_most_viewedtbl
GROUP BY tour_id
ORDER BY tour_id
LIMIT 10;
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select tour_id, count(*) as total_count
from tourism_most_viewedtbl
group by tour_id
order by tour_id ASC
limit 10
```